# r - rmongodb $or query construction

Tags: r, rmongodb

**Background**

I have [GTFS](https://developers.google.com/transit/gtfs/reference) data stored in a local mongodb database.

The `calendar` table looks like

```
field      | type
service_id | varchar
monday     | int (0 or 1)
tuesday    | int (0 or 1)
...
sunday     | int (0 or 1)
```

**Task**

I would like to select all the `service_id`s for which any weekday (Monday to Friday) = 1, using the `rmongodb` package in `r`.

In SQL this would be something like: `SELECT service_id FROM calendar WHERE monday = 1 OR tuesday = 1 OR ... OR friday = 1`

**Detail**

When using the [Robomongo](http://robomongo.org/) GUI the query is:

```
db.getCollection('calendar').find({"$or" : 
    [{'monday':1},
    {'tuesday':1},
    {'wednesday':1},
    {'thursday':1},
    {'friday':1}]
})
```

which returns 8 documents (see image)

[image: robomongoQuery]

Therefore, in `r` I'm trying to construct the same `or` query that will return the same results, but I'm not having any luck.

```
library(rmongodb)
library(jsonlite)
## connect to db
mongo <- mongo.create()
mongo.is.connected(mongo)
db <- "temp"

## days for which I want a service:
serviceDays <- c("monday","tuesday","wednesday","thursday","friday")
```

Attempt 0:

```
## create list as the 'query' condition
ls <- list("$or" = 
         list("monday" = 1L, 
              "tuesday" = 1L, 
              "wednesday" = 1L, 
              "thursday" = 1L, 
              "friday" = 1L))

services <- mongo.find.all(mongo, "temp.calendar", query=ls)
## returns error:
Error in mongo.find(mongo, ns, query = query, sort = sort, fields = fields,  : 
  find failed with unknown error.
```

Attempt 1:

```
## paste the string together
js <- paste0('{"', serviceDays, '":[',1L,']}', collapse=",")
js <- paste0('{"$or" :[', js, ']}')
## this string has been validated at jsonlint.com

bs <- mongo.bson.from.JSON(js)
## run query
services <- mongo.find.all(mongo, "temp.calendar", query=bs)
## result
> services
list()    ## empty list

## manually writing the JSON string doesn't work either
# js <- '{"$or" : [{"monday":[1]},{"tuesday":[1]},{"wednesday":[1]},{"thursday":[1]},{"friday":[1]}]}'
```

Attempt 2:

```
## create the or condition using R code
l <- as.list(sapply(serviceDays, function(y) 1L))
bs <- mongo.bson.from.list(list("$or" = list(l)))
## run query
services <- mongo.find.all(mongo, "temp.calendar", query=bs)
## result
> length(services)
[1] 2    ## 2 documents returned
```

The two documents returned are for `service_id`s where all of monday, tuesday, wednesday, thursday, friday = 1. i.e., it seems to have used an `AND` clause, not an `OR`.

Attempt 3:

```
## deconstruct the JSON string (attempt 1)
js <- fromJSON(js, simplifyVector=FALSE)
bs <- mongo.bson.from.list(js)

## run query
services <- mongo.find.all(mongo, "temp.calendar", query=bs)
## result
> services
list()    ## empty list
```

what's wrong with my query attempts in `R` that prevents me getting the same 8 documents I get when using the Robomongo GUI?

Comment: Attempt 0 isn't passing json. Try wrapping your `ls` in `toJSON(ls)`.

Comment: @BrandonBertelsen `?mongo.find.all` - the `query` argument accepts a list. It turns out that I needed to put each `or` condition inside its own list too (see my answer)

Comment: It's tricky, I've had problems with it myself but more for posting data rather than retrieving it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My 'attempt 0' was close, but I was missing more `list` arguments.

```
ls <- list("$or" = list(list("monday" = 1L), 
                    list("tuesday" = 1L), 
                    list("wednesday" = 1L), 
                    list("thursday"= 1L), 
                    list("friday" = 1L)))
## json string:
> toJSON(ls)
{"$or":[{"monday":[1]},{"tuesday":[1]},{"wednesday":[1]},{"thursday":[1]},{"friday":[1]}]} 
## run query:
services <- mongo.find.all(mongo, "temp.calendar", query=ls)

## result
length(services)
[1] 8
```

Comment: Seems you answered yourself, so please, close question.

Comment: @DmitriySelivanov I have to wait 6 more hours to accept my own answer ;)